# Problem when unlocking account in private ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I tried this statement

> **personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, "password")**

But I am getting this error .

**Error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden**

Any suggestion would be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: I am doing this in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: you run `personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, "password")` on console?

Comment: try to use "--allow-insecure-unlock" option when runnning geth

Comment: Have a look over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/truffle-migrations-account-locked-error-with-network-command/10840#10840 Hope it helps.

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69435/error-account-unlock-with-http-access-is-forbidden-when-unlock-an-account-in-ge