# Private Ethereum blockchain Transaction Issue

Tags: go-ethereum, sendtransaction

Sending ether from one address to another using web3js. Getting issue of "account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

Probably the unlocking process for you account has not completed at the time of transaction.

May be there is a solution in this answer: 
[Error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden when unlock an account in Geth console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69435/error-account-unlock-with-http-access-is-forbidden-when-unlock-an-account-in-ge)

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a private network using geth, by default as a security measure unlocking account via HTTP is forbidden, you can overcome this issue with a simple flag that you should provide when launching the network:

`--allow-insecure-unlock`

Example:

```
geth --allow-insecure-unlock

Ensure this flag is added when launching the private network
```

`--allow-insecure-unlock -> Allow insecure account unlocking when account-related RPCs are exposed by http`